# OpenCart enable / disable entire shop

Tags: opencart

I once wanted to hide my OpenCart webshop from the public until I finished it.
Somewhere in the OpenCart Admin panel there was an option to enable / disable the entire shop.

Unfortunately I do not find this option anymore.

Could anybody please tell me where this option is located at?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programmatic problem at all. It suits more for OpenCart forums where you can ask about how to administer the OpenCart store. If you'd read the *tag wiki* for `opencart` tag you'd knew this...

Comment: Ask it on http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Login in to admin panel.
2. Go to `System > Settings`
3. Click on `Edit` button of your store.
4. Select `Server` tab.
5. Set `Maintenance Mode:` option as `Yes`.

This setting prevents customers from browsing your store. They will instead see a maintenance message. If logged in as admin, you will see the store as normal.

That's it.

Have a nice day !!